# MATLAB: GUIDE "Save Figure" toolbar button

Tags: matlab, user-interface, save, matlab-guide

I created a Gui in GUIDE and added the predefined "Save" toolbar button in guide->tools->toolbar. When i press the save button, the next time i open the GUI it will show the saved values and axes.

Now i would like to remove that feature again, but only removing the save button doesn't seem to work. The Gui still opens with the last saved values.

Is there a way to clear the saved data?

Comment: Are you using persistent variables? Have you tried `clear all`?

Comment: `clear all` doesn't help and no, i am not using persistent variables. any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that no further answers are forthcoming, and since I just ran across the same issue, this is what I did.

1. Open the object browser and determine which ones changed;
   In my case it changed two text boxes as well as the axes.
2. Open the properties inspector for the changed objects and edit as required to return them 
   to their original states. I replaced the string property with the correct values.
3. It's too difficult to figure out how to make the axes object revert to it's old state. You can create a  2nd temporary axes and copy those states to the first axes; but I found this doesn't work.  Instead, delete the old axes, create a new axes in it's place, and rename the tag to match the original.  If there are any callbacks, make sure they're in the right place and delete the old one.

That's it. Good luck.